# How do I send email from a react app using SMTP

Tags: reactjs, email

i have a webform written in react - i would like an email sent to an admin when someone submits something from it.

I had a look at [emailjs](http://www.emailjs.com/) which looked promising, but it looks like it was attempting to execute the email send at the browser side... duh!

How do I send the email from the server side (i.e. from the webserver) so that I may use the local smtp server to relay the email?

Answer (score -1):

I'd spin up a node.js app and use nodemailer (https://nodemailer.com).

Also, beware that sending mail from 'localhost' is likely to get your messages caught in spam. I highly recommend using a service like mailgun.com (free) to delivery your messages so you don't have to worry about SPF records, DKIM records and IP Address "warmup".

Comment: so a separate app that listens on say a rest endpoint to actually send the email? :-(